# Implement nested interface of generic parent class with ironpython

Tags: c#, generics, ironpython, masstransit

I wan't to implement the following C#/.Net interface with IronPython:

```
public static class Consumes<TMessage> where TMessage : class
{
   public interface All
   {
       void Consume(TMessage message);
   }
}
```

This is the python code I tried so far:

```
class TestMessage(object):
     pass

class TestConsumer(Consumes[TestMessage].All):
     def Consume(self, message):
         pass
```

From this I get the following exception:

> TypeError: TestConsumer: cannot inhert from open generic instantiation MassTransit.Consumes`1+All[TMessage]. Only closed instantiations are supported.

A valid C# class definition to implement this interface looks following:

```
public class TestConsumer : Consumes<TestMessage>.All
{
    public void Consume(TestMessage msg) { }
}
```

So is it not possible to implement this kind of in IronPython? Or am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you either provide IConsumer or remove it from your sample. I don't expect it to be relevant but who knows.

Comment: Removed it. It is just an empty marker-interface used internally by Masstransit. Thank you for your hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like implementing the nested interface as

```
class TestConsumer(Consumes[TestMessage].All):
```

does not correctly bind the type parameter `TMessage` even though that would be expected from the syntax.
If the type is provided at the end ("for the interface instead of the surrounding class") it seems to work as expected:

```
class TestConsumer(Consumes.All[TestMessage]):
```

What would also work is importing the interface `All` explicitly and use it looking like a standalone generic interface:

```
from MyLib.Consumes import All
class TestConsumer(All[TestMessage]):
```

It does not seem obvious if this behavior is correct/defined that way or if there is a bug in the [type generation](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Runtime/Types/NewTypeInfo.cs) (besides from the "inhert"-typo) or in the way the generic parameters are defined/bound. It looks to be also accepted to bind the parameter twice:

```
class PyTestConsumer(Consumes[String].All[String]):
```

even with different values which does not make much sense looking at it from a .NET perspective:

```
class PyTestConsumer(Consumes[List[String]].All[String]):
```

Comment: So, if I understand you right, this is a bug in the current IronPython type generation impl. and a nested interface in a generic class cannot be implemented. Unfortunatly I cannot change the class or interface as it is in 3rd party code.
Anyways, thank you for the educated answer!

Comment: No I speculated that there might be a bug. The second and third of my class definition code snippets should allow you to implement the `All`-interface for your use-case.

Comment: Ah okay, so I think that is a bug. But as you suggested, the second and third solution works.

Comment: And just as an interesting note: I know don't implement the interface directly in the python-script, but use https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface to cast the script scope, which defines the right methods and properties, to generate a dynamic proxy implementing the .Net interface.